# Project tasks report show #Days to deadline positive values

Tags: python, report, project, odoo, odoo-10

In report "Tasks Analysis" in module "Project" when I select the measure "#Days to deadline" it shows negative values for those tasks that have missed deadline. Can I somehow format that field to show positive values in this report?

Note: in database view this field must not loose sign because users use filter "#Days to deadline" less than 0" to filter out all tasks that have missed deadline.

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the issue, it will help us a lot.

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas Added image:)

Comment: Wait users search in the view/pivot to find tasks? Because normally you search in tasks to find tasks :-P So you should change the view and invert the sign or just extend the view with another value "inverted #Days to Deadline".

Comment: @CZoellner Yes, :D. Users, asked to see a report on delayed tasks only. They apply a filter on the report so that only delayed tasks appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I do not have access to the enterprise codebase I will give you an answer based on the community:

The `Tasks Analysis` is a report.

In our case we have the following at play:
`Tasks Analysis` button which invokes the `action_project_task_user_tree` which in turn shows the report views(pivot/graph) of the `report.project.task.user`. Now this report gets its data from `addons/project/report/project_report.py`

So basically what you have to do is change the sql statements in `_select` and specifically how the `delay_endings_days` is calculated.

Since you mention:

> Note: in database view this field must not loose sign because users use filter "#Days to deadline" less than 0" to filter out all tasks that have missed deadline.

You could add another field that has that calculation and hide this one.

This is the straightforward solution, you can go ahead and make changes on the widget that renders the record to show whatever you want, but I am not sure if you want to go down that path.

Comment: Thank You for this solution. Following it I added additional field. delay_endings_days_2 whose value is constructed exactly as delay_endings_days_2 and then abs() is applied. :)